# MS Word: INCLUDEPICTURE field code

Tags: windows, ms-word, fieldcodes

Sorry, Google hasnt been very helpful.

I have a Word Document which references jpeg pictures stored at a different path.

I always instruct word to Link in the file and modify the field code as:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE \d"..\\Relative Path\\To\\MyPicture.jpg" }
```

For some inexplicable reason, if either the picture content changes or if the document is closed and opened several times, the field code is getting updated automatically.

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE \d"c:\FULL Path\\To\\MyPicture.jpg" \* MERGEFORMATINET }
```

How do I ensure that the field code remains intact no matter what I do?

Comment: Did this used to work? Are you saving as .htm or web page format? (I think that's what brings in the mergeformatinet)

Comment: An update is due here. I realized that there were problems with .docx. With the file saved as a .doc, sanity was restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue too.

I fixed this by using `.dot` instead of `.dotx`.
For some reason the newer format is changing the link.

Not a solution, but it is a workaround

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes. I stored my document as .doc and there were no issues thereafter.